# Reset customized input shiny R using shinyjs::reset

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, shinyjs

I have a shiny module for a customized input, and i'm trying to add a button to reset this custom input (both interface and server) every time this button is clicked. Below is an example using shinyjs::reset:

app.R

```
    library(shinyjs)
library(rintrojs)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)

source("customTextInput.R", local = TRUE, encoding = "UTF-8")

ui <- fluidPage(

    useShinyjs(),

    # Assembling page
    dashboardPage(

        # Assembling header
        dashboardHeader(title = "Custom Inputs", titleWidth = 1294), 

        # Assembling sidebar
        dashboardSidebar(

            sidebarMenu(
                menuItem("Custom inputs reset", tabName = "custom", icon = icon("search"))
            )

        ),
        # Assembling the body of the page
        dashboardBody(

            tabItems(
                tabItem(tabName = "custom",
                        br(),
                        br(),
                        customTextInputUI("text1"),
                        fluidPage(

                            textInput(inputId = "text2", label = "Native text input", width = "100%"),
                            actionButton(inputId = "reseter1", label = "Reset custom"),
                            actionButton(inputId = "reseter2", label = "Reset native")

                        ),
                )

            ) 

        )

    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

    {### Reset -----

        observe({

            shinyjs::onclick("reseter1", {
                reset("text1")
            })

        })

        observe({

            shinyjs::onclick("reseter2", {
                reset("text2")
            })

        })

    }

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

customTextInput.R

```
library(shinyjs)


{# UI Module -----

    customTextInputUI <- function(id, addWidth = "100%", addHeight="64px", addTop="5px", addValue = "") {

        if (is.null(addValue)){addValue <- ""}

        ns <- NS(id)

        return(

                fluidPage(

                    HTML(

                        sprintf(

"
<form id='%s' autocomplete='off' class = 'form-group shiny-input-container' style = 'padding-top:%s; width:%s; height:%s;'>
    <label for='%s'>Custom text input</label>
        <input charset='UTF-8' type='text' class = 'form-control' 
        id='%s' data-slots=' ' value = \"%s\"  
        data-shinyjs-resettable-id='%s' data-shinyjs-resettable-type='Text' data-shinyjs-resettable-value='' required>
</form>", ns('textBloco'), addTop, addWidth, addHeight, ns('textInput'), ns('textInput'), addValue, ns('textInput')))

                )

          )

    }

}
```

In this case, reseter2 can reset shiny text2 native textInput, however reseter1 cannot reset custom input text1.

Why there's such unexpected behavior? Is there any workaround for it, maybe using pure javascript?

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 2):

If you check the input id for `text1` then you will see this is displayed as `text1-textBloco`
[image]

So to get your `reset` to work you can update it as `reset("text1-textBloco")` then it should work.

Alternatively, you could update the `customerTextInput.R` where it has `ns('textBloco')` inside `sprintf` to just `id` then it should work with `reset("text1")` in `app.R`.
So `sprintf()` will be something like:

```
sprintf(    
            "
<form id='%s' autocomplete='off' class = 'form-group shiny-input-container' style = 'padding-top:%s; width:%s; height:%s;'>
    <label for='%s'>Custom text input</label>
        <input charset='UTF-8' type='text' class = 'form-control' 
        id='%s' data-slots=' ' value = \"%s\"  
        data-shinyjs-resettable-id='%s' data-shinyjs-resettable-type='Text' data-shinyjs-resettable-value='' required>
</form>", id, addTop, addWidth, addHeight, ns('textInput'), ns('textInput'), addValue, ns('textInput')))

      )
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Indeed, I already have tried your proposal, but, the things get ugly when you have an input inside label. Besides that, what i'm really looking foward is a way to render the element again if possible, because the reset only bring value to default value, but i need to bring the style too.